# Prove that $\cos (1/z)=\alpha$ has infinitely many solutions in $D_{r}(0)$ for any $r>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find the type of singularity in $g(z)=\cos(1/z)$.
For all complex number $\alpha$, find all solutions to the equation $g(z)=\alpha$.
Prove that $\cos (1/z)=\alpha$ has infinitely many solutions in $D_{r}(0)$ for any $r>0$

First, I have shown that it has essential singularity by using the Laurent series centered at $z=0$, that is
$$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{(2n)!z^{2n}}$$
Since there are infinitely many negative terms $a_n\neq 0$, $g$ has essential singularity at the origin.

For the second part, $\cos(1/z)=\alpha$, then I get
$$z = \frac{1}{\cos^{-1} \alpha}$$
Then I have no idea how to evaluate this equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to solve the equation $\cos w=\alpha$, that is
$$
\frac{e^{iw}+e^{-iw}}{2}=\alpha\implies e^{2iw}-2\,\alpha\,e^{iw}+1=0.
$$
Can yo follow from here?

Comment: By following your method, I use quadratic formula and get $$e^{iz}=\frac{2\alpha+(4\alpha^2 -4)^{1/2}}{2}=\alpha+(\alpha^2-1)^{1/2}$$
Then I get $$z=\frac{1}{i}\log[\alpha+(\alpha^2-1)^{1/2}]$$
Is it correct?

Comment: Sorry shoud be $$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{i}\log[\alpha+(\alpha^2-1)^{1/2}]$$ and $$z=\frac{i}{\log[\alpha+(\alpha^2-1)^{1/2}]}$$ Then how can i conclude that it has infinitely many solutions for any $\alpha$?

Comment: It is correct. You have to take into account that the square root has two values and the $\log$ infinitely many.

Comment: But how to show that it is true in a disk of radius $r$ for any $r>0$?

Comment: The values of $\log z$ are $\log|z|+i\operatorname{arg}(z)+2\,k\,\pi\,i$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I know this. Then can i say that by letting $k=\alpha+(\alpha^2-1)^{1/2}$,$$z=\frac{i}{\log k}=\frac{i}{\ln |k|+i \arg k}=\frac{i(\ln |k|-i \arg k)}{(\ln |k|)^2+(\arg k)^2}=\frac{\arg k}{(\ln |k|)^2+(\arg k)^2}+\frac{i \ln |k|}{(\ln |k|)^2+(\arg k)^2}$$
And hence for any $r$, I can find infinitely many $k$ such that $\cos (1/z)=\cos[(\log k)/i]=\alpha$?

Comment: No. $\alpha$ is fixed. Let $w=\alpha\pm\sqrt{\alpha^2-1}$. Then $1/z=\ln|w|+\operatorname{arg}w+2\,k\,\pi\,i$.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that $cos(w)=\alpha$ has infinitely many solutions in $U=\{w:|w|>1\}$. 
Where does the map $z\mapsto \dfrac{1}{z}$ take the unit circle $D=\{w:|w|<1\}$?
What are the implications for $\cos \circ \dfrac{1}{z}$?